# Forward port 80 on ZTE MF283

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding

I am currently trying to setup a server at home and to do that i turned off virtual servers and configured a DMZ. I got a PfSense device between to do some subnetting, but i think thats not relevant (All port forwarding works). I already got many services to work, but i can't get HTTP working, because I always get to the webinterface of the router.
Is there any way to reroute connections coming from the WAN to the DMZ? If yes can i still access the interface internally?

Comment: Lol pfsense in the middle is **always** relevant... :-p it sounds like your router is picking up the request before it reaches pfsense. Check in the router settings if you can move it's webgui port settings to 8080, (443 if you are not already using it) or 8443. Honestly, you may want to try and disable the admin access facing the internet from this router. If you need remote admin access to the router, setup an instance of OpenVPN on pfsense for it. At least then you know it's not responding to Russian Hydra attacks! You too can prevent Russian bot-nets! 